# SQLite запрос на выборку не уникальных значений

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица author, в ней поля id и author_id имеющее повторяющиеся значения.
Нужен запрос на выборку автора с наибольшим количеством одинаковых author_id.

```
Таблица такая:
1 25
2 25
3 17
4 8
5 8
6 8
```

Пока написал только такой: `SELECT author_id, Count(author_id) AS author FROM author GROUP BY author_id`, но нужно еще как-то выбрать из них одно максимальное значение. Help

Версия SQLite 3.15.0

Comment: `SELECT author_id, Count(author_id) AS author FROM author GROUP BY author_id ORDER BY author DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Спасибо большое